# I am getting error when creating a storage for variables

Tags: react-native, variables, expo

My code -

```
export default Users = [
    {
        id: 1,
        email: "user1@email.com",
        username: "user1",
        password: "password",
        userToken: "token123",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        email: "user2@email.com",
        username: "user2",
        password: "pass1234",
        userToken: "token12345",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        email: "testuser@email.com",
        username: "testuser",
        password: "testpass",
        userToken: "testtoken",
    },
];
```

Error -

```
ReferenceError: Users is not defined
Module.D:\Code\WhiteHatJr\Apps\unused_seller\model\users.js
D:/Code/WhiteHatJr/Apps/unused_seller/model/users.js:1
> 1 | export default Users = [
  2 |     {
  3 |         id: 1,
  4 |         email: "user1@email.com",
View compiled
```

I am making an app using react native, expo.
But I am facing this error. Don't know why.
But it seems like there is a problem with the variable I am using for storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```js
const Users = [
    {
        id: 1,
        email: "user1@email.com",
        username: "user1",
        password: "password",
        userToken: "token123",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        email: "user2@email.com",
        username: "user2",
        password: "pass1234",
        userToken: "token12345",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        email: "testuser@email.com",
        username: "testuser",
        password: "testpass",
        userToken: "testtoken",
    },
];

export default Users
```

Answer (score 1):

See, you don't actually need that name (`Users`) here, as it won't be used anyway when module is imported. Quoting the doc:

> Named exports are useful to export several values. During the import,
> it is mandatory to use the same name of the corresponding object.
> [...] **But a default export can be imported with any name**, for example:

```
// file test.js
let k; export default k = 12;

// some other file
import m from './test'; 
// note that we have the freedom to use import m instead of import k,
// because k was default export
console.log(m);        // will log 12
```

As you don't need the name, you can make this quite concise:

```
export default [
    {
        id: 1,
        email: "user1@email.com",
        username: "user1",
        password: "password",
        userToken: "token123",
    },
    // ...
];
```

But if you actually need this data to be properly labeled, consider dropping `default` altogether and going the named exports road instead. [In some teams](https://blog.neufund.org/why-we-have-banned-default-exports-and-you-should-do-the-same-d51fdc2cf2ad), [default exports](https://blog.piotrnalepa.pl/2020/06/26/default-exports-vs-named-exports/) [are](https://backstage.io/docs/architecture-decisions/adrs-adr003) [considered harmful](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2019/01/stop-using-default-exports-javascript-module/).